# How to discover an EntityProperty's qualifiers?

Tags: entity, properties

`EntityProperty`s have a qualifier form in the documentation,

$\text{EntityProperty}\left[\text{type},\text{pname},\left\{\text{qual}_1\to \text{val}_1,\text{qual}_2\to \text{val}_2,\ldots \right\}\right]$

I never gave much thought to this until I saw this usage in an example in the documentation which returns a `TimeSeries` object.

```
EntityValue[
 Entity["AdministrativeDivision", {"California", "UnitedStates"}], 
 EntityProperty["AdministrativeDivision", "CivilianLaborForce", 
  {"Date" -> All, "Frequency" -> "Monthly", "SeasonalAdjustment" -> "NotSeasonallyAdjusted"}]]
```

This demonstrates that I am missing out on some powerful options for `EntityProperty`.  I tried to investigate these *qualifiers* with:

```
EntityProperty["AdministrativeDivision", "CivilianLaborForce"]["Qualifiers"]
```

and also

```
EntityProperty["AdministrativeDivision", "CivilianLaborForce"]["Properties"]
```

but received an `"UnknownSubproperty"` error in both cases.

When working with an `EntityProperty` how can I discover its *qualifiers*?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It can be tricky to find in the docs, but [`EntityValue`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/EntityValue.html) is what is needed. Unfortunately, I don't see my following usage documented anywhere.

```
EntityValue[EntityProperty["AdministrativeDivision","CivilianLaborForce"], "Qualifiers"]
(* {Date,Frequency,Modifier,SeasonalAdjustment,TimeSeriesOperator} *)
```

The syntax can be occasionally be slightly more terse, where the third argument is an "annotation".  This use is documented.

```
EntityValue["AdministrativeDivision", "CivilianLaborForce", "Qualifiers"]
(* {"Date", "Frequency", "Modifier", "SeasonalAdjustment",    "TimeSeriesOperator"} *)

EntityValue["AdministrativeDivision","CivilianLaborForce", "QualifierValues"]
(* {Date->{},Frequency->{Annual,BiWeekly,Daily,Monthly,Quarterly,Weekly},
    Modifier->{GDPFraction,NationalPercent,PerCapita},
    SeasonalAdjustment->{NotSeasonallyAdjusted,SeasonallyAdjusted},
    TimeSeriesOperator->{AnnualChange,AnnualizedChangeRate,Change,ChangeRate,YearOverYearChangeRate}} *)
```